# Difference between two MAX date Power BI DAX expressions

Tags: powerbi, dax

What is the difference between these two DAX expressions

[Max Date]:= MAX(DatesTable[Date])

If, in another measure, I then use it the following way:

FILTER(ALL(DatesTable), DatesTable[Date]<=[Max Date])

But then, I try this instead:

FILTER(ALL(DatesTable), DatesTable[Date]<=MAX(DatesTable[Date]))

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first example you calculated the MAX and pushed the result to a measure.

```
[Max Date]:= MAX(DatesTable[Date])
```

The measure can be used accross your report

In the second example you have a DAX expression where you directly use the result of the MAX in a filter.

```
FILTER(ALL(DatesTable), DatesTable[Date]<=MAX(DatesTable[Date]))
```

Now you cannot use this max in your report as a measure.

there is a third concept of variables. Most people want to keep the overview and use variables in their dax expressions:

```
MaxRowFilter = 
    var maxDate = MAX(DatesTable[Date])
    return FILTER(ALL(DatesTable), DatesTable[Date]<= maxDate )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the measure branching technique you are calling a measure in the row context inside FILTER, a measure always has an invisible CALCULATE wrapped around it so the code that you think is same isn’t actually same, your first code looks something like this to the DAX Engine:

FILTER (
ALL ( Dates ),
Dates[Date] <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( Dates[Date] ) )
)

Calculate converts each row into Filter Context that defines what MAX would return. For each cell of the below visual, FILTER iterates ALL dates and then for each row iterated, CALCULATE performs context transition and shifts the currently iterated date in the row context to an equivalent filter context, once the calculation for one cell of the report is complete CALCULATE + MAX always return the last date, and then I get the COUNT which is the same as the number of rows in the Dates table.

But in the second code there is no CALCULATE around MAX, so MAX is getting filtered by the filter context that is created by the report so for each month I get Current Month + COUNT of all the previous months.

Moral of the short story, don’t create measures for code that you are going to use for evaluating or filtering tables. Always split the code into variables so that you won’t encounter hidden calculate. For example your First code will work if you store the [Max Date] in a variable and since variables are just constants it won’t invoke context transition.